# Split lines into two Strings using BufferedReader

Tags: java

I want to split each line into two separate strings when reading through the txt file I'm using and later store them in a HashMap. But right now I can't seem to read through the file properly. This is what a small part of my file looks like:

```
....
CPI       Clock Per Instruction 
CPI       Common Programming Interface [IBM]
.CPI      Code Page Information (file name extension) [MS-DOS]
CPI-C     Common Programming Interface for Communications [IBM]
CPIO      Copy In and Out [Unix]
....
```

And this is what my code looks like:

```
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("akronymer.txt"));
        String line;

        String akronym;
        String betydning;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] linje = line.split("\\s+");

            akronym = linje[0];
            betydning = linje[1];

            System.out.println(akronym + " || " + betydning);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Feilen som ble fanget opp: " + e);
    }
```

What I want is to store the acronym in one String and the definition in another String

Comment: So what is stopping you?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think, The way OP is `splitting` the String on `whitespaces`.

Comment: @Smit That looks fine to me.

Comment: My errors, I've been trying for a while now.. I get the acronym right, but my code only stores the first word in the definition. Kinda need some help now

Comment: @user3037979 That is because you are splitting by spaces. If you want to stop once you reach the second string, add `2` as a maximum strings argument.

Comment: And make sure the returned String array has indeed 2 elements. Otherwise, one can make your program abort by feeding it an acronym without a betydning in one line. Or just an empty line, in which case you don't even have an acronym ....

Comment: @PeterLawrey That was my point you just mentioned in your previous comment.

Comment: @Smit which is why I +1 your comments ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that whitespace in the definition is interpreted as additional fields.  You're getting only the first word of the definition in `linje[1]` because the other words are in other array elements:

```
["CPI", "Clock", "Per", "Instruction"]
```

Supply a `limit` parameter in the [two-arg overload of `split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), to stop at 2 fields:

```
String[] linje = line.split("\\s+", 2);
```

E.g. `linje[0]` will be `CPI` and `linje[1]` will be `Clock Per Instruction`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to limit your split to only two parts then use `split("\\s+", 2)`. Now you are splitting your line on every whitespace, so every word is stored in different position.